# Postfix throttling for outgoing messages

Tags: postfix, rate-limiting

I need Postfix to send outgoing messages (from local PHP) with a certain rate. Say, one message in 120 seconds. Any messages exceeding this rate should be queued (delayed) and delivered later.

[Policyd](http://www.policyd.org) is not what I'm looking for. I don't need limiting overall number of messages sent. I need a pause (120s) between any two messages beeing sent.

Tried this config, but it's not working:

```
initial_destination_concurrency = 1
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 120
default_destination_recipient_limit = 1
default_process_limit = 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You need to set

```
default_destination_recipient_limit = 2
```

instead of 1. Because if set to 1 then the limit will only apply to the same recipient, **not** domain.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use postfwd. I use it in production for rate limiting servers.

http://postfwd.org/doc.html#examples

Answer (score 2):

You can throttle outbound emails:

```
default_destination_rate_delay = 1s
```

Postfix will add a delay between each message to the same receiving domain with a delay of 1 second. The default value is 0s.

Comment: According to the manual, http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_destination_rate_delay   , it should larger than 1s.

Answer (score 1):

### Slow down clients sending mail too fast

smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 100

smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100

smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 200

smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 100

#

check this out

Comment: Won't work. I need a very low rate. Something like this:
blah_blah_rate_limit = 0.01
Seems like commands you suggest are for incoming mail, not outgoing.

Comment: For anybody wondering, "smtpd_client_message_rate_limit: The maximal number of message delivery requests that any client is allowed to make to this service per time unit ... The time unit is specified with the anvil_rate_time_unit configuration parameter." and "anvil_rate_time_unit (default: 60s)". So you can specify low rates as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that the above config is not working, is it not working to the same destination or to different destinations?

As far as a suggestion, it would be fairly trivial to script an on/off iptables rule to block outgoing connections to port 25. That would be my next suggestion.

Comment: Not working even for the same e-mail address. 100 messages to one particular e-mail are sent in about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's really common for people to do this for email going to yahoo.  You can look at an example configuration at http://old.nabble.com/Create-Custom-Mail-Queue-td21577217.html#a21577217 , and tweak the numbers as you need.

Comment: The example is now available here https://web.archive.org/web/20120618134726/http://old.nabble.com:80/Create-Custom-Mail-Queue-td21577217.html#a21577217

Answer (score -1):

Maybe playing a bit with qmgr you could obtain some results.

http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html