# Postfix limit total sent per hour

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, spam, rate-limiting

I'm not after services that could provide me with fancy fine-grained control like `policyd`, I don't need per user/domain control, I only want to:

> limit maximim number of emails that could be sent trough Postfix mail
>   system per hour, preferably but not necessary excluding domains that
>   Postfix mail system itself handles.

Let's say I want to set limit of 200 messages per hour. Desired behavior is that 201 message holds until one hour period is over in order to be delivered.

I would be really amazed if solution to this could respect my previously set per-domain rate limits:

```
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 3s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 2
```

**EDIT:**
here are some configuration options that *might be* related to what I'm looking for:

```
anvil_rate_time_unit = 120s
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 4
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 4
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 1
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 1
```

This configuration should limit 4 emails per 2 minutes, thus 120 per hour - but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: A very crude approach would be to rate limit outgoing connections using IPtables.

Comment: @AndréBorie Would that be feasible?

Comment: Feasible, yes. But also awful and definitely not the right tool for the job.

Comment: If you used iptables you would need to disable connection cache

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of:
http://serverfault.com/questions/110919/postfix-throttling-for-outgoing-messages? 

I also don't understand why you think that smtp_destination_rate_delay won't do what you need....

Comment: @DictatorBob `smtp_destination_rate_delay` applies per domain, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Postfix to divert all messages to the [hold queue](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#hold_queue), and an external script (which you'll need to write) can monitor this queue and release messages at the desired rate.

Comment: Sorry but this answer was not helpful.

Comment: @busythomas I found it helpful, at least gives a piece of the puzzle. I actually really like that, I can program any algorithm I want to manage the emails.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix does not have that feature by default, you will have to use external program policyd to enforce that rule.
I believe you will find the knowledge you seek in this link:
http://ngocquyetlinux.blogspot.com/2013/05/limit-mail-with-policyd.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried policyd and unfortunately it was causing high server load. I do not recommend Policyd.